# Best way to keep IPFS daemon alive

Tags: linux, ipfs

I'm building an app using IPFS for decentralized storage, but right now I only have 1 node.

I run ***ipfs daemon*** from ***tmux*** but the daemon won't stay alive for long periods of time, and I can't figure out why. Regardless, I need to do something to keep the daemon alive if it dies.

Comment: give a try using a supervisor: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_supervision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run IPFS daemon through "screen", works fine! Try "screen" utility.

Comment: How to do that exactly?

Answer (score 7):

Run the daemon in the background

```
ipfs daemon &
```

Comment: It kept running for about a day or two and stop working. Is there a way to auto-restart it if it is offline somehow?

Comment: @TerryWindwalker you can use docker in that case `docker run --restart=unless-stopped -p 4001:4001 -p 5001:5001 -p 8080:8080 ipfs/go-ipfs`

Answer (score 0):

As you run `ipfs` by using `ipfs daemon` inside `tmux`, the solution is **surprisingly simple**:

```bash
while :; do
    ipfs daemon
    sleep 1
done
```

or a one-liner:

```bash
while :; do ipfs daemon; sleep 1; done
```

If you want to keep the daemon alive, you can re-run it whenever it dies. Therefore, just wrap around everything with a "while `true`" loop, the `sleep 1` is optional.

If you want to **shutdown** this while loop, just attach to the tmux session by `tmux a`, then press `Ctrl+C` twice *quickly*.